# Trying to read XML attributes from multiple files and replacing them with a number 1.25 times greater than they were before

Tags: bash, sed, variable, xml, xmlstarlet

I am trying to write a bash script or something similar, that I can use to modify all occurrences in a bunch of xml files with one click. I have 24 xml files, each containing a few dozen lines and with the attribute `Torque="SOMENUMBER"` inside them about 3-5 times each. I would LIKE to replace those with 1.25 times their value to simply add 25% torque to every motor in this game.

(Doing it this way would be useful, since mods and game patches will overwrite these and I can quickly experiment with other values.)

I came up with the idea to use `sed -n -e 's/Torque="\(.*\)"/\1/p' <filename.xml` to extract the number, put it in a variable and then I would have no idea how to get it back in there at the right place and also the `sed` command above outputs all occurrences of Torque at once.

xmlstarlet could probably do it from what I have googled, but it always complains about the xml files containing more than one root element. Maybe I should somehow add a temporary tag `<root_temp><\root_temp>` around everything somehow, let xmlstarlet run its magic, remove the tags again and save the file? It's been years, since I dabbled with bash scripts, I would also be willing to do it with python, cpp, learn the basics of a new language, I don't care xD

Sample XML:

```
<_templates>
    <Engine>
        <RUScoutModernEngine BrakesDelay="0.5" />
    </Engine>
</_templates>
<EngineVariants>
    <Engine
        _template="RUScoutModernEngine"
        CriticalDamageThreshold="0.7"
        DamageCapacity="120"
        DamagedConsumptionModifier="1.2"
        EngineResponsiveness="0.35"
        FuelConsumption="1.5"
        Name="ru_scout_modern_engine_0"
        Torque="70000"
        DamagedMinTorqueMultiplier="1.0"
        DamagedMaxTorqueMultiplier="0.6"
        MaxDeltaAngVel="0.01"
    >
        <GameData
            Price="1900"
            UnlockByExploration="false"
            UnlockByRank="1"
        >
            <UiDesc
                PLACE="HOLDER"
            />
        </GameData>
    </Engine>
    <Engine
        BLA="BLA"
        Torque="80000"
        BLA="BLA"
    >
        <GameData
            Price="5500"
            UnlockByExploration="true"
            UnlockByRank="1"
        >
            <UiDesc
                PLACE="HOLDER"
            />
        </GameData>
    </Engine>
    <Engine
        BLA="BLA"
        Torque="76000"
        BLA="BLA"
    >
        <GameData
            BLA="BLA"
        >
            <UiDesc/>
        </GameData>
    </Engine>
</EngineVariants>
```

Comment: Apart from the missing root node, you also seem to have duplicate attributes in some nodes.

Comment: That is unfortunately how this particular game sets up its "xml" files, nothing I can do about that. Although the "BLA BLA" stuff was added by me to filter out unimportant information and make the file more palatable, if that wasn't clear. The <Engine> tags do each contain the same attribute with different values, though I do not think that counts as a duplicate, since it IS a different tag, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML fragments (files with more than one root node) are very difficult to manage, very few tools accept them directly. Adding a wrapper element "by hand" is a good idea; note also the technique described in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571941/making-use-of-an-xml-file-with-more-than-one-root-element/23574398#23574398

Once you have a well-formed document, doing the update you want in xmlstarlet or in Saxon's Gizmo (https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!gizmo) should be straightforward [self-interest declared]. In Gizmo it's

```
update //@Torque with .*1.25
```

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, I find xmlstarlet a bit confusing for now, though. Probably better to try this "Gizmo" approach. Am I correct, that I have to install the whole Saxon Suite or whatever it is to get access to Gizmo?

Comment: Yes, the Gizmo tool is just a front end exposing a selection of the transformation capabilities of the Saxon engine. But it's just a JAR file...

Comment: Are multi-root XML documents even valid? From my understanding they are not - a document must have no more than one root element

Comment: Firstly, I think you mean "well-formed" - validity is something different. This "multi-root" thing is not a well-formed document, but it is a well-formed external general parsed entity, which means it's not supposed to be used on its own, but it can be incorporated into a multi-entity document by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a fake root node around your broken XML is easy enough, modifying the modified XML would be a breeze with `xmlstarlet`, and deleting the added root node (and the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` that `xmlstarlet` adds) once you've modified it is not too hard either:

```bsh
{ echo '<root>'; cat file.xml; echo '</root>'; }  |
xmlstarlet ed -u '//Engine/@Torque' -x '. * 1.25' |
sed '1d; 2d; $d'
```

This obviously assumes that the XML that comes out of the `{ ...; }` bit is actually a well-formed XML document (you have duplicated attributes in your example document).

---

The same thing as above, but using `xq` (an XML parser wrapping around `jq`, available as part of `yq` at https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bsh
{ echo '<root>'; cat file.xml; echo '</root>'; }  |
xq -x '.root.EngineVariants.Engine[]."@Torque" |= ( tonumber * 1.25)' |
sed '1d; $d'
```

The `xq` output does not contain `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

---

Repeating this for all files whose names match `*.xml` in a directory, using the `xmlstarlet` variant of the code above as an example:

```bsh
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

for pathname in ./*.xml; do
    cp "$pathname" "$tmpfile" &&
    { echo '<root>'; cat "$tmpfile"; echo '</root>'; } |
    xmlstarlet ed -u '//Engine/@Torque' -x '. * 1.25'  |
    sed '1d; 2d; $d' >"$pathname"
done

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Note that the above does an in-place edit on the matched files.  You may want to test this on a *copy* of your files first!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by implementing the option with a temporary root node to make it valid and then using Gizmo as suggested. For anyone stumbling upon this later, here is my solution.

I downloaded the java version of [Saxon Home Edition](https://www.saxonica.com/download/java.xml), unpacked it in a subfolder called "Saxon" and used the following script successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

#remove script and generate it with the following lines (that way I only need
#to include my one .sh file)
rm -f script
echo update //@Torque with .*1.25>script
echo save temp_updated.xml method=xml indent=yes>>script

#we do the following to all xml files in the subfolder "classes/engines/"
for filename in classes/engines/*.xml
do
    #cleanup in case they got leftover, which is important for Gizmo,
    #otherwise I get a thousand "Overwrite File" prompts, which is
    #not conducive to automating the process.
    rm -f temp.xml
    rm -f temp_updated.xml

    #make a new temp file, starting with the temporary root element,
    #append the original file and close the root element
    echo "<xml_temp>">temp.xml
    cat $filename>>temp.xml
    echo "</xml_temp>">>temp.xml

    #call Saxon with the correct codepath, start the Gizmo subroutine or whatever
    #take the temporary file as input and "script" as the commands to be executed
    java -cp "Saxon/saxon-he-10.5.jar:Saxon/jline-2.14.6.jar" net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:temp.xml -q:script
    #sed -i for inplace editing of the file
    #the first expression '$d' removes the last line (the closing temp root tag)
    #the second impression removes the first line (Gizmo tags on some kind of xml info
    #and the second line, which contains the starting temp root tag
    sed -i -e '$d' -e 1,2d temp_updated.xml

    #I force overwrite the old file with the new and improved xml
    cp -f temp_updated.xml $filename
    #...and clean up after myself
    rm -f temp.xml
    rm -f temp_updated.xml
    rm -f script
done
```